# BeautifulSoup and lxml modifying tags unexpectedly

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, lxml

I'm currently manipulating vendor-proprietary xml files with Python 3.11. I'm noticing that when processing the files, some of the tags are being modified for seemingly no reason. Here's a couple of examples:

```
<check_type:"Windows" version:"2"> is becoming <check_type: version:="">
<user:"Administrators"> is becoming <user:>
<file_acl:"ProgramFiles"> is becoming <file_acl:>
```

I've tried looking through the documentation but I'm not seeing anything that matches this behavior in either of these packages.

My original intent is to remove certain items tagged with <custom_item>. This is working as intended. Here's how I'm processing the data:

```
def build_audit_file(items, file):
    """
    Removes specified item from audit file.
    Params:
    items - list - passed-in items to remove
    file - str - passed-in filename of the audit file we're presently working
    """
    # Open specified audit file
    file = open(file, 'r')
    # Read data in from audit file
    file_data = file.read()
    # Close audit file gracefully to prevent corruption
    file.close()
    # Parse the data read from the file as HTML. XML doesn't work on the
    # audit files because of their formatting, but the data is actually XML.
    html_data = BeautifulSoup(file_data, "lxml")
    for item in items:
        # Remove check that matches the FP or exception name
        for tag in html_data.find_all(lambda t: t.name == "custom_item" and 
                                     item in t.text):
            tag.extract()
    # Convert html_data into a string so we can manipulate it while printing to 
    # a new file if needed in the future.
    new_audit_file_data = str(html_data)
    # Split the data apart at newlines so we can better parse it.
    new_audit_file_data = new_audit_file_data.split("\n")
    # Derive output file name from the provided base file we're using
    output_file_name = root_directory + "\\output\\XFP-" + file.name.split(
        "\\")[-1]
    # Create and open the output file
    output_file = open(output_file_name, "a")
    # Write lines to file, while removing injected html, p, and body tags
    for line in new_audit_file_data:
            if "<html><body><p>" in line:
                output_file.write(line.replace("<html><body><p>", "") + "\n")
            elif "</p></body></html>" in line:
                output_file.write(line.replace("</p></body></html>", "") + 
                                  "\n")
            else:
                output_file.write(line + "\n")
    # Close the output file gracefully
    output_file.close()
```

Any ideas how to ensure the tags other than <custom_item> are left alone?

Comment: The content you posted is not XML it's just nonsensical garbage, and you're parsing it as HTML which means the parser will try to "fix up" what it finds, in an ad-hoc manner too since lxml's HTML parser is an ad-hoc HTML4 parser. So you're clearly in a situation where you're making garbage go through garbage, and then you ask why you get garbage out.

Comment: Right, I can't do anything about the content going in. The XML parser won't detect it as it's not actual XML, but that's how the vendor is writing their files. Modifying tags with regex doesn't work very well, so a HTML parser is the best tool I've found so far, although I'm open for suggestions.

Comment: A bespoke parser would almost certainly work better. The biggest issue will be getting a complete spec for that horror show.